# Check if each array value matches result from database

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to check if an any value in an array matches the result from the database, and if it does, then I want to echo a checked checkbox and a filled in text input.

Here's what I have so far.

```
$faucets_checked = unserialize($rotator_websites);
$check_these = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= (intval(count($faucets_checked))-1); $x++){
$faucet_website_checked = explode("=",$faucets_checked[$x]);
$check_these[] =  $faucet_website_checked[0] . "=";
$ref_these[] = $faucet_website_checked[1];
}

//SELECTED SOME DATA FROM DATABASE

while($stmt->fetch()){

                $count = 0;
                while($count <= (intval(count($check_these))-1)){
                  $check_this = $check_these[$count];
                  if($check_this == $faucet_website){
                    $checked = "checked";
                    $ref_filled = "value='".$ref_these[$count]."'";
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='".$faucet_id."' ".$checked." /><input type='text' name='text".$faucet_id."' ".$ref_filled." />";
                  }else{
                    $checked = "";
                    $ref_filled = "";
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='".$faucet_id."' ".$checked." /><input type='text' name='text".$faucet_id."' ".$ref_filled." />";
                  }
                  $checked = "";
                  $ref_filled = "";
                  $count++;
                }

}
```

I find that this does return a checked box and input text field where it is supposed to but also returns a another that isn't check and isn't filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i miss somthing but if you want checks if a value exists in an array the function ["in_array()"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is for you

Comment: WOW! I didn't even know this existed. Thank you